# Does the matlab executable query the license server?

Tags: matlab, unix

I have a matlab code that I need to run in batch mode. However, due to license limitations, it can't be done on matlab simply.

Will running the matlab executable (hoping to do it using mcc command) in batch via the unix environment require matlab licenses or just C compilers in different machines?

Comment: Sorry, licensing questions are off-topic for StackOverflow -- and that's something that you should anyhow get from a trusted source (normally the company itself) rather than strangers in the internet.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because licensing questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you have the MATLAB Complier, you can create a stand-alone executable that you can distribute to others and doesn’t require a license to run. That is, the crested executable is free from any licensing requirements from the MathWorks. You don’t require a C compiler for this, there is no C code involved. Your MATLAB code is packaged and encoded, and can then run on the MCR, a special version of the MATLAB interpreter crested specifically for this purpose.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I converted my matlab script into the compiled executable using -mcc command. I believe that is free from licensing issue. Now what I need to do is run the executable from some kind of shell script and pass on 1000 different random matrices for 1000 different inputs. And submit the script to be run parallelly among different processors. Do you think this idea is good to go or has some flaws I can't see due to my limited knowledge about scripts?

Comment: That's exactly how I've used it in the past. You can run these on a HPC cluster, or simply on a multi-processor system. I've also used a MATLAB script to start up these jobs on various computers across our local network, wait for each to be done, and start a new one on that machine. That one was fun to figure out. But the Parallel Computing Toolbox might be a simpler solution nowadays.

Comment: Sure. Just one last question. As I mentioned, I have to run the matlab executable code for 1000 different inputs, and further for each input 300 different runs to capture the statistics of the randomness. What I want to ask is can I load all the inputs in a file and then each time the shell script is run, pass on one input and save its output perhaps in a .mat file? Or maybe 300 different iterations and for each iteration output of all the inputs saved in a .mat file?
What will be your comment on this?

Comment: @CrisLuengo This is so that you read the above comment.

Comment: You can do any of those options. What's best depends on a lot of things. I have no idea what your data, your output or your resources look like. Do whatever you feel comfortable with. If there's a performance issue, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sure. Thanks a bunch for helping.

Comment: @CrisLuengo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63429701/does-the-following-sh-script-qualify-to-be-processed-parallely