# Does the following .sh script qualify to be processed parallely?

Tags: matlab, unix

So I generated the compiled executable of a matlab script using -mcc command to be able to run the executable using unix environment so as to not query the matlab license server. I believe the executable doesn't require license requirements.

To see if what I am trying to do is along the right lines, I tried doing what I want to for a toy matlab script(Called sineplot).

In the image attached, the script calls the mcc generated sineplot.sh thousand times. I am also passing two input arguments to the script which are as follows:-

1. **Loop Count:** Basically the matlab script loads a .mat file which contains a 1*1000 array.
   Depending on the loop count, a distinct value from the array is picked for different
   amplitude sine wave. That is why the loop count information is being passed.
2. **File Name:** To save the output of each count, I am passing a different file name for each count.

Being fairly new to all of this, I have a question: If I submit this script to be run parallelly in different machines(using the LSF), will the different runs be all executed parallelly? Is the script potent enough to do that? Or something else needs to be done too.

[Script invoking mcc generated .sh file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS10R.png)

Script:

```sh
!#/bin/bash

echo "This script is about to call another script"

lc=1

while [ lc -le 1000]

do

sh ~/run/sine_plot.sh /apps/mathworks/matlab/R2018a $lc,out$lc.mat

lc=$(($lc+1))

done

echo "Another script called"
```

Comment: You need to use `ssh` or similar to execute your script on a different computer. If on an HPC, you should schedule the jobs in that loop, using whatever facility is provided by the cluster. If running in parallel locally on your computer, use `parallel`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm sorry, I am now have pasted the text. Can you explain that schedule the jobs part?

Comment: It depends on how and where you want to run the script. If we’re talking about an HPC cluster, your admin should be able to help you run the script in parallel, we can’t help with that because we don’t know anything about the particular cluster you want to use.